# pickle.dump showing ordinal_encoder not defined even when it is

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I am using pickle.dump to pickle ordinal encoder so that I can encode the data I receive from the website.
When using the pickle.dump command, it says 'ordinal_encoder not defined'
More information that might be relevant:
on hovering over sklearn.preprocessing (the library from which I imported the encoder), it shows "Import "sklearn.preprocessing" could not be resolved" but the encoder still works in the notebook code.
also, when I try to print head of encoded dataframe, it also says not defined, but the model still somehow got trained and everything.
there were no problems in pickling the xgboost model either.

I tried to pickle the OrdinalEncoder() using it's variable name 'ordinal_encoder' in the pickle.dump command
but it says ordinal_encoder not defined.

Here's an image for more context.

[image: here's an image for more context]

Answer (score 0):

Based on that screenshot of a (Jupyter) notebook session, you're probably not running all of the cells in order.

You will need to run the first cell, the one that assigns the name `ordinal_encoder`, before attempting to run the latter cells that use that name.

The same stands for `label_X_train`, which is defined in the first cell and only used in the second.

In other words: click "Run All".

Comment: run all was giving that output but then i tried running the individual cells, so the outputs changed and everything that included the use of sklearn is throwing an error. I have tried  downloading sklearn in the venv using pip but its still not working

Comment: If you run `!pip install scikit-learn` in one of the cells, it should certainly install it.